# isAnnotationPresent returns false when used in Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, reflection, annotations

After I created a Java EE web application archive, the method `isAnnotationPresent()` returns `false` when I call the following code, while it works fine in plain Java SE. The Method should find all Tests from a Class. The following Method is in a seperated component.

```
for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
   // only method with @Test
   if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
```

I've tried to do it with the full class name and its the same result.
When I iterate over all `Annotation`s via `m.getAnnotations()` and print it, then the `Annotation` is present.

Could this be a Classloader problem?

Comment: *"Could this be a Classloader problem?"* Almost. This problem can be caused by having physically multiple `Test.class` files in the runtime classpath, usually caused by a wrong/dirty build. E.g. one in /WEB-INF/classes and one in JAR(s) in /WEB-INF/lib, and/or server/lib, etc. This can at least not be pointed out exactly based on the sparse information provided so far in the question. It doesn't contain any clues about the build procedure being used.

Comment: I'm using Maven for the build procedure. The Component for finding the Tests is an dependency in the web application project. The Test Annotation is from TestNG which is also provided as dependency.

Comment: What is scope of TestNG dependency?

Comment: The scope of TestNG is runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same issue. In a simple .jar or .war, everything would work fine, but once packaged into an .ear, it would start acting up. As @BalusC said in his comment, the problem was that the annotation class was present in multiple places, in my case it was both in .ear/lib and in .ear/.war/WEB-INF/lib because the dependency was declared in the parent pom.xml. Once I made sure the dependency is `<scope>provided<scope>` in the .war and .jar modules, it would get packaged only inside .ear/lib, and it would work fine again. In my case.ear/lib was the correct location as the library was shared between the modules inside the .ear, but in your case some other place may be the correct one, depending on what modules actually require this class. In either case, make sure the class (or the .jar containing the class) is only ever present once in the final artifact and in the deployment environment.